# Placement of earlier features in more complex features in CNN

Tags: neural-networks, feature-selection, deep-learning, feature-engineering, convolution

I'm trying to understand convolutional neural networks better. I've been doing different tutorials, but there are some basics concerning how the hidden units represents features that I really would like to have clarified.

Look at the following picture (from slide 31 from www.cs.stanford.edu/people/ang//slides/DeepLearning-Mar2013.pptx by Andrew Ng):

[image]
When combining features from layer 3 (object parts) to layer 4 (object models), how does the specific hidden unit know where to place the different features? I would guess it would know that the hidden unit should represent 0.3 x "mouth feature" and 0.6 x "eyebrow feature", but how does it know to place the eyebrow above the mouth?

Thanks. Any links to books or websites with easy-to-understand material on this would also be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A neural network does not actually **know**/**understand** like humans do.

A neural network is nothing but a fancy name for application of Non-linearities to a signal.

That being said, this **knowing** simply comes from training the Neural Network over thousands/millions of examples. This training gradually keeps optimizing the weights and biases to minimize the loss function, which in this case leads to combination of the right parts of the images.

This must sound dull, but this is what neural networks do.